# Check Names pointing to Python Object

Tags: python

How can I get a list of all the names that point to a Python object?

```
import my_function from example

a = my_function
b = my_function

get_names(my_function)
[a, b]
```

Edit: The goal is to help find how to monkey patch an object that is loaded in an unknown way.

Comment: Where is `get_names` defined?

Comment: @wundermahn I think that's the question: how to write a function `get_names`?

Answer (score 2):

Search the global namespace for objects matching via identity, and report the keys (names).

```
def my_func():
    pass

a = my_func
b = my_func

def get_names(x):
    for k, v in globals().items():
        if v is x:
            yield k

print(list(get_names(my_func))) #prints ['my_func', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

See below (use globals and make sure you do not return the function itself)

```
from example import my_function

def get_names(func):
  result = []
  for k,v in globals().items():
    if v == func and k not in str(v).split():
      result.append(k)
  return result



def foo():
  pass

a = my_function
b = my_function
c = foo

print(get_names(my_function))
```

example.py

```
def my_function():
  pass
```

output

```
['a','b']
```